# Aliens and continence

Tags: science-based, biology

Since I'm not getting a lot of biology-based details here, I asked [over here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92477) instead.

(Original question follows...)

---

Here's a somewhat odd question that got me thinking lately... would an alien be [continent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/continence) (able to control their voiding), and would this be innate or learned?

Why does it matter? Well, debates about how continence works in humans aside, this is definitely something that can vary! [Pierson's Puppeteers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierson%27s_Puppeteers) are stated to be naturally incontinent, and there are terrestrial species such as rats that are incontinent. At least one story (sorry, don't recall the title offhand) has postulated that humans, under the right circumstances, would not learn continence. (I would guess that most marine animals are also incontinent, because why would they need to be otherwise?) On the opposite end, some carnivore species such as cats are born "hyper-continent"; they need help from their mothers to void at all.

Ignoring societal factors (i.e. focusing on a species' pre-sapience starting point and/or what we might expect would happen to an individual "raised by wolves"), what factors would influence an organism's level of continence, both at birth, and learned as the organism matures? Again, I'm looking for whether they would be 'naturally' continent (e.g. most predators) absent the pressures of 'civilization' as opposed to not caring, rather than whether they are *capable* of learning continence. **I'm also looking particularly at what change, if any, would occur as the organism matures from an infant to adult.**

**Note 1:** I'm looking for a *general* answer rather than one for a specific species, both because that will be more useful to others, and because I do not have a single species for which I would like to know. However, if additional focus is required, feel free to restrict answers to land-based vertebrates. I'm also looking for non-opinion answers backed up by trends seen in terrestrial animals, hence the use of `science-based`. (So, for example, my "knee-jerk" answer would be that carnivores are born hyper-continent and learn what we would consider "human-typical" continence, while herbivores are born and would remain, absent "artificial" influences,  incontinent. However, is this actually justified by terrestrial biology, or is it, if you'll pardon a more-appropriate-than-usual expression, a load of manure?)

**Note 2:** To clarify, what I mean by "continence" is the typical ability of an organism to *consciously* control when and where the it voids — "psychological" continence, if you will, as opposed to "physiological" continence, which would be whether or not the organism is physiologically *capable* of such control (which most animals are, barring health issues or other physical abnormalities). Using Puppeteers as an example again, they possess the *physiological* capability (as evidenced by Nessus and others that interact directly with humans), but most lack *conscious* control, and so by my definition are (psychologically) incontinent.

**Note 3:** As far as trying to answer this question, I should note that humans training an animal would constitute "societal factors", which I'm asking to ignore. (In short, if I add a societal desire for continence, then physiological continence will almost surely result in psychological continence as well. Again, my objective is investigating continence *before* — hence my focus on how continence is affected by maturation — or *in the absence of* such factors.) That said, [AlexP](/users/29552/alexp) makes a pertinent point, which is that we can't really *know* whether a non-sophont is physiologically continent. However, I believe an educated guess can be made based on whether individuals are observed to "be discriminating" in where, when or how they choose to do their business. Cats are an excellent example of animals which *do* exhibit such behavior, while rats are a good example of animals which do not. I would expect that comparing the behavior of infants to adults would also be informative. (I would also argue that this is what makes this a world-building question as opposed to a straight biology question. For real animals, it may well be impossible to say, but for aliens created by a writer, obviously said writer can make a decision. The goal of this question is to obtain evidence from the real world in order for such a decision to be informed rather than just "whatever the author feels like".)

Comment: No, I think he means what he says...  Continence as in "not needing diapers"

Comment: [Right](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/continence); see definition 1. Or, as stated in the question, "able to control their [voiding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/void#Verb) [of bowel and/or bladder]".

Comment: +1 Interesting question.  I don't have the science to answer it but my first instinct would be to investigate why rats are incontinent.  There must be some evolutionary advantage which has split them from the mainstream.   As omnivores, they are like us, mixing the predator's need to hid its presence with the herbivores need to fertilize the land.  But unlike us, they are scavengers and carrion eaters.  I'm betting that these are the sides of their nature which has led to incontinence.  Neither their native environment nor their (dead) prey mind fecal odor, so why bother to contain it.

Comment: @HenryTaylor, while you could look at it that way (and for a quick way to help other readers understand my meaning, it works), diapers are a modern invention, and plenty of cultures, even now, don't use them. Nor would an alien species necessarily *need* them. The aforementioned Puppeteers AFAIK have no such thing. I am specifically *not* looking for how a society might address biological continence issues, although that could make an interesting, if separate, question.

Comment: A very interesting line of speculation indeed! Though I fear your query will eventually be closed for lack of focus or being opinion based. Your general question you already answer yourself: aliens might be continent or incontinent. Opinions could go either way and be equally valid. I wonder if you could focus on a single problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I know of any mammal (including marine ones) who are inherently incontinent.

Comment: @elemtilas, if I have to, I can ask multiple questions about more specific critters. However, this is *not* opinion-based; I'm asking for direction *backed up by real examples*. If there is insufficient real-world precedent for a non-opinionated answer, well then, that *is* an answer.

Comment: @Alexander, at least [rats](https://www.museumoflondon.org.uk/Resources/e-learning/introduction-to-museum-pests/s02p06.html) are, allegedly. (Although there are also reports that they can be trained, but their *natural inclination*, which is what I'm asking about, is incontinence.)

Comment: Rats are supposed to leave a dottet trail of urine a faeces wherever they go? I don't believe you. I think that rats, like all mammals, urinate and defecate when they want to or feel like it, and not all the time. Please provide a supporting citation.

Comment: @AlexP, firsthand experience (I've had "pet" rats). Also, you are saying the Museum of London, previously sited, is full of the aforementioned feces? Maybe they don't "leak", per-se, but I would question how much conscious control they have without having to learn it. That said, this gets into a valid point that there is a difference between *physiological* incontinence (literal dribbling) and *psychological* incontinence (larger releases, but still with minimal *conscious* control). I'm mainly asking about the latter.

Comment: @Matthew Do you define continence as the natural habit of "holding it", or natural ability (but not the habit) of doing so. The latter ability is common even among birds.

Comment: @Alexander, will answer in an edit.

Comment: The equivalent of human psychology is called [ethology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology) in other animals. For obvious reasons, we cannot say anything certain about the mental life, if any, of non-human animals; it is not clear what you mean by "conscious control" in non-human animals. As far as I know, all mammals which are not too stupid (and don't have physiological restrictions, such as rabbits) can be potty trained.

Comment: It's opinion based in that we simply don't have any real examples of sophonts other than humans to go on. To my knowledge, all humans, as animals, are continent and all civilisations & societies expect people -- their own and visitors alike -- to exhibit continence. All answers about non-human sophonts are therefore entirely speculative.

Comment: @elemtilas, you're adding in *societal* factors, which I have specifically asked to exclude (I have, in fact, said to exclude factors resulting from sapience, so not having other sophont example is irrelevant). I'll agree that from a *societal* perspective, the question is probably opinion-based, but I'm explicitly *not* asking about that, but rather for what we *know* from terrestrial biology. I've basically said in the question "please check your opinions and tell me only facts".

Comment: Okay, it wasn't my intention to focus on societal factors! Even focusing strictly on biological factors, the matter is, as you admit in your query, entirely opinion based: *for aliens created by a writer, obviously said writer can make a decision*. Again, we only have one example of a sophont species (for lack of a better example, that would be us) to go on. That's not much to extrapolate from! This is why your query ultimately comes down to opinion: **there is no way to offer a science-based response**. There is nothing to compare with.

Comment: @elemtilas, but we *aren't* without knowledge. We can observe animal behaviors and make inferences. We know that rats appear to be incontinent (by the definition I'm using). We know that kittens *can't* 'go' unless licked by their mothers. I'm sure there is similar information available for other species; I'm particularly interested in herbivores since all I really "know" about them is inferences from Niven, which could be totally wrong. I was hoping to get the attention of someone that actually knows such information, as it's hard to search for online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: question isn't about world-building per se and has recently been duplicated (sans "aliens") over on Biology.SE (https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92477/what-do-we-know-about-continence-in-animals)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because We answer "specific and answerable" questions, must include specifics to judge "What will make one answer better than another?". We don't answer non-specific qustions which " I do not have a single species for which I would like to know" - limiting to "all land based vertebrates" is too broad. An "educated guess" is out of scope with using the [tag:science-based] tag.

Comment: (Agreeing with [elemtilas](/users/37029)...)

Comment: If you think this is off-topic because there is a question in biology.se, we could close maybe 15% of the questions in this site. On top of that, the question in biology.se does not cover aliens.

Comment: @Renan: there are several factors at play. The OP doesn't really seem to want to deal with aliens so much as real world animals, the question is now off topic because there is no *specific* worldbuilding problem. (Yes, real world queries are on topic here, but we have to have some kind of fictional context to go on!) The question, as asked also lacks focus. Given the OP's desire for a biological approach, they have now asked on Biology where the question is actually on topic (sans the "alien" red herring of this question). ...

Comment: Since it is now asked in the other place, this query is not only off topic here but also a duplicate. Since the OP actually desires biological answers, I hold that the best course was to close this query in favour of the better worded one on Biology. As for closing 15% of the queries here, that's always something the community can look at! If a question is a bad fit here, but it's on topic elsewhere, *and it's also asked somewhere else*, then by all means, close it here!

Comment: @Matthew -- I appreciate your forebearance & patience!, and also apologise for any misunderstandings on my part (re societal factors, etc). I do think your moving this to Biology.SE was for the best; but I'd like for you to consider revisiting the topic here, in all its societal glory! Once you get a handle on how this works in animals, maybe then come back & consider the question of aliens!

Comment: @elemtilas, perhaps... it would be fun just to see what people have to say, but harder to not make it opinion-based .

Answer (score 6):

Continence is important to predators and territorial non-predators to be able to mark territory. You can't pee to assert dominance if your bladder has been dribbling the past few hours, the tank is empty.

It is important for prey animals so as to leave fewer clues to be tracked with. Urine and feces are both powerfully odoriferous. To void your bladder or bowels at an inopportune time is to send up a gigantic alert to the immediate vicinity "there's meat somewhere close!".

Additionally, urine can be a sexual signal among Earth vertebrates. Both male and female pheromones are occasionally present, and a female can advertise that she is in heat and receptive to mating. It's not difficult to imagine the same being possible for a hypothetical male animal (that it is receptive, not that it is in heat). For highly selective females, it might make sense to withhold that signal until the male has been vetted.

Finally, some herbivores are known to (in specific scenarios) consume their own feces. Rabbits are the most well known, but other rodent-like animals also do this. It's theorized that this is a source of nutrients produced by their gut bacteria, but since they lack the more sophisticated digestive system of ruminants, it needs to make a second trip through. If the aliens had some similar mechanism, then again, it might make sense for them to be continent... don't want to lose the good stuff while you're running away from the Venusian T-Rex.

The lack of these factors or similar won't necessarily result in incontinence, but continence wouldn't be selected for without some mechanism like the above.

Comment: "Theorized"? AFAIK, not only is this [widely accepted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit#Digestion), such critters pass two distinct types of droppings, only one of which is reingested. Combined with their diet and non-ruminant digestive system (this is their version of chewing cud), it's hard to believe this *isn't* how things are supposed to work. That said, would you assert that Niven's Puppeteers being incontinent is — can't get over how appropriate the expression is  — a load of fertilizer?

Comment: Niven deserves many different sorts of criticism, but I don't think that's a valid one. Everything I've said is very circumstance dependent. If the main branch of animal(-like) biology on Pierson's planet did not develop strong senses of smell, then prey animals might have no evolutionary pressure to be continent. Continence is a quite useless feature otherwise (until civilization, where it has some maintenance value... fewer janitors are needed, but I doubt evolution could care about such things).

Answer (score 1):

I figure it would be a matter of brain power, mobility, safety as a youngling, and cleanliness. So if they're not big enough they can't. If they are able to move around from birth and don't get left in one place, they probably won't develop it. If they're mobile, but carried by members of their family at a young age, they probably will. If they have a den that scents could lead predators to, they will.